# GET request to ListAPIView doesn't recognize query parameter in Django Rest Framework test case

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I am encountering an issue with my Django Rest Framework test case where a GET request to a ListAPIView doesn't seem to recognize a query parameter. The same request works correctly when sent through Postman, but fails when executed within the test case.

[image]

**Here's an overview of the problem:**

I have a ListAPIView that represents a collection of model instances. The view works fine when tested manually through Postman, and it expects a query parameter called **'project'** to filter the collection based on a specific project.

However, when I try to send a GET request to the same ListAPIView within my test case, the query parameter **'project'** is not recognized, resulting in an error response indicating that the project field is required.

**Here's a simplified version of the relevant code in my test case:**

```
class ShiftListTests(APITestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser', password='testpassword')
    self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user)

    self.project = Project.objects.create(owner=self.user, task='Test Task',
                                          technical_requirement='Test Requirement', start='2023-05-01',
                                          hourly_rate=10.0)

    self.shift1 = Shift.objects.create(project=self.project,
                                       start_time=timezone.make_aware(timezone.datetime(2023, 5, 1, 9, 0, 0)),
                                       end_time=timezone.make_aware(timezone.datetime(2023, 5, 1, 17, 0, 0)))
    self.shift2 = Shift.objects.create(project=self.project,
                                       start_time=timezone.make_aware(timezone.datetime(2023, 5, 2, 9, 0, 0)),
                                       end_time=timezone.make_aware(timezone.datetime(2023, 5, 2, 17, 0, 0)))

def test_get_shift_list(self):
    url = reverse('shift list')
    payload = {'project': self.project.id}
    response = self.client.get(url, data=payload, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
    # Assertion and further processing...
```

**Error:**

```
Failure
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/Tokio/Developer/ShiftBot/shift/tests/testShiftListEndPoint.py",
    line 44, in test_get_shift_list
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
    AssertionError: 400 != 200

{'project': ErrorDetail(string='This field is required', code='invalid')}
```

I have verified that the URL is correct, the payload is properly constructed, and the data argument is passed correctly to the client.get() method. I have also confirmed that the project field is included in the GET request when testing with Postman.

I suspect that there might be some difference in how the request is processed or handled between the test environment and the actual API server, causing the query parameter to be ignored or not recognized within the test case.

Any insights or suggestions on why the query parameter is not being recognized within the test case, and how to resolve this issue, would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Add your view function/class to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try Sending the data in json dumps

`data={'data': json.dumps(payload)}`

Also generally if you need to send the request body, ideally a POST request should be used.

Comment: This doesn't work. I need to get a list of all shifts belonging to one project. As I understand I need to pass the ID of the project through a query, but how to do this correctly I do not understand. I think there should be some standard practice for such trivial things. Maybe you know how these things are usually done? Thanks

Comment: Please pass this project_id to query params
something like -> /?project_id=1